# Div arranging in other div gives wrong layout

Tags: html, layout

I have some page that keeps some information that needs to be aligned.

I'm not sure how to make it work, but it keeps putting it on the wrong place.

I think something goes wrong when i use div in a div.

What i want is:

[image]

This is (in short) what i have:

```html
<div width="100%" style="border: 1px solid black">
<table width="200px">
<tr><td colspan="2" style="text-align: center">Totaal</td></tr> 
<tr><td>A</td><td style='text-align: right'>A</td></tr>
<tr><td>B</td><td style='text-align: right'>B</td></tr>
<tr><td>C</td><td style='text-align: right'>C</td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2">Gegevens Wissen</td></tr>
</table>
</div>
<div width="100%" style="border: 1px solid black">
<div style="border: 1px solid black">
<table>
<tr><td width="100px">Groep</td><td style="text-align: right">1</td></tr> 
<tr><td>A</td><td style='text-align: right'>A</td></tr>
<tr><td>B</td><td style='text-align: right'>B</td></tr>
<tr><td>C</td><td style='text-align: right'>C</td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2">Gegevens Wissen</td></tr>
</table>
<table style="float: left;">
<tr><td width="100px">Serial</td><td style="text-align: right">111</td></tr>
<tr><td width="100px">In Groep</td><td style="text-align: right">1</td></tr>
<tr><td>A</td><td style='text-align: right'>A</td></tr>
<tr><td>B</td><td style='text-align: right'>B</td></tr>
<tr><td>C</td><td style='text-align: right'>C</td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2">Gegevens Wissen</td></tr>
</table>
<table style="float: left;">
<tr><td width="100px">Serial</td><td style="text-align: right">222</td></tr>
<tr><td width="100px">In Groep</td><td style="text-align: right">2</td></tr>
<tr><td>A</td><td style='text-align: right'>A</td></tr>
<tr><td>B</td><td style='text-align: right'>B</td></tr>
<tr><td>C</td><td style='text-align: right'>C</td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2">Gegevens Wissen</td></tr>
</table>
</div>
<div style="border: 1px solid black">
<table>
<tr><td width="100px">Groep</td><td style="text-align: right">2</td></tr> 
<tr><td>A</td><td style='text-align: right'>A</td></tr>
<tr><td>B</td><td style='text-align: right'>B</td></tr>
<tr><td>C</td><td style='text-align: right'>C</td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2">Gegevens Wissen</td></tr>
</table>
<table style="float: left;">
<tr><td width="100px">Serial</td><td style="text-align: right">333</td></tr>
<tr><td width="100px">In Groep</td><td style="text-align: right">2</td></tr>
<tr><td>A</td><td style='text-align: right'>A</td></tr>
<tr><td>B</td><td style='text-align: right'>B</td></tr>
<tr><td>C</td><td style='text-align: right'>C</td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2">Gegevens Wissen</td></tr>
</table>
<table style="float: left;">
<tr><td width="100px">Serial</td><td style="text-align: right">444</td></tr>
<tr><td width="100px">In Groep</td><td style="text-align: right">2</td></tr>
<tr><td>A</td><td style='text-align: right'>A</td></tr>
<tr><td>B</td><td style='text-align: right'>B</td></tr>
<tr><td>C</td><td style='text-align: right'>C</td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2">Gegevens Wissen</td></tr>
</table>
</div>
</div>
```

Can anyone help me?